# Class inside a Div, only working once

Tags: class, html

new to the forum, as this is the first time i haven't been able to use search to solve my issue, maybe its my wording.
I'm hoping one of you guys could help me.

I have a problem, i have written a class for my navbar, which i would like to apply to all links as well. I have a 3 column layout, all wrapped in a container (so i can have a sticky footer). the class in my header works, but for the life of me i cant figure out why it wont apply the the sidebar navigation. Each section of the page (header,col1,col2,col3 and the footer) has an ID, and inside which i have told it to apply my nav class, but to no avail.

Sorry if you don't get me, but any help would be much appreciated .

regards

Update...
It works here,

```
<div id="header">
</br>
<img src="images/banner.gif" href="index.html" width="60%"
alt="RedHotPolka">
<br/>
<div class="nav1">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
<a href="about.html">About</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
```

But not here...

```
<div id="rcol" align="right">
<div class="nav1">
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a href="featured.html">What's hot?</a><br/><br/>
<a href="sale.html">Sale</a><br/><br/>
</div>  
</div>
```

the css im using..

```
.nav1
a:link {text-decoration:none; color:#000000; font-size:22px; padding:4px;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none; color:#000000;}
a:active {text-decoration:none; color:#ff0000;}
a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#ff0000;}
```

And

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

html, body {height: 100%;}

#container
{
    min-height: 80%;
overflow:auto;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#footer
{
position:relative;
margin-top: -100px;
height: 100px;
clear: both;
}

#header
{
margin-bottom: 10px
}

#lcol
{
float: left;
width: 20%;
margin-left: 0%;
display: inline;
}

#mcol
{

float: left;
width: 48%;
margin-left: 6%;
}

#rcol
{

float: right;
width: 20%;
margin-left: 6%;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: We will need to see your code or a sample of it, to help u out .

Comment: Alright, sorry to waste your time guys, but ive just changed the font, and for some reason its now working? odd stuff. cheers for all the views, im sure it won't be long till we meet again, Thanks, Joe